# MATLAB pie labels turn off interpreter

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, interpreter

I want to plot a pie from a string vector that I get from another function.
These strings include `_` symbols and the labels use the default interpreter and show special symbols instead of the original strings.
How can I turn off the interpreter there?
(I tried some commands such as `set(Groot, 'defaultLegendInterpreter', 'none')` and  `pie(categorical(str_vec),' Interpreter',' none')` but nothing was good.)

```
str_vec = ["a_l" "a_l" "ab" "ab" "c_m"];
figure;pie(categorical(str_vec))
```

[image: pie]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore the `pie` function with `edit pie`, and with a little digging we can see that each pie "slice" is created as a `patch` object, and each label is created as a `text` object. Notably, the `text` object creation only uses the following properties:

```
text(xtext,ytext,labels{i},...
  'HorizontalAlignment',halign,'VerticalAlignment',valign,...
  'Parent',cax,'Layer','front');
```

i.e. it doesn't set the `Interpreter` property, which is `'tex'` by default. This means we're not going to be able to set it while calling the `pie` function and will have to do it after the chart creation.

You can set all of the text objects' interpreter to `'none'` using

```
% Assign output objects to variable 'p', inc. the text labels
p = pie(categorical(str_vec)); 
% Get the text objects from the pie chart
labels = p( arrayfun( @(x) isa(x,'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'), p ) );
% Set their interpreter
set( labels , 'Interpreter', 'none' );
```

If you're not familiar with `arrayfun` which I'm using to condense things here, you can do the same thing with a loop

```
p = pie(categorical(str_vec)); 
for ii = 1:numel(p)
    if isa(p(ii),'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text')
        set( p(ii), 'Interpreter', 'none' );
    end
end
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

This (post-hoc modification of properties) works on your example. You might need some further iteration and condition statements to deal with more complicated plots.

```
str_vec = ["a_l" "a_l" "ab" "ab" "c_m"];
fh=figure;pie(categorical(str_vec))

fh.Children(1).Children(1).Interpreter='none'
fh.Children(1).Children(5).Interpreter='none'
```

[image]